# How can I install URLScan?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, installation, extension

I went to the official Microsoft site to install URLScan 3.1 from [here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/urlscan)

However, the `Web Platform Installer 4.6` is unable to find the extension to `IIS`. I've looked in the complete list, as well as under the server product list (which should be a subset).

My O/S is `Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise` and I'm using `IIS 7.5`, which appear to be supported.

Any idea why the Web Platform Installer can't find the product? I couldn't find any information suggesting that the product is deprecated.

EDIT: I was able to download it directly from [here](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9655678). However, as pointed out by MichelZ, I'm not sure if it is now obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

This is built into II7 now. See [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering)

> Request Filtering is a built-in security feature that was introduced
>   in Internet Information Services (IIS) 7.0, and replaces much of the
>   functionality that was available through the UrlScan add-on for IIS
>   6.0.

Comment: Hmm the documentation for URLScan says that the pre-requisities are "IIS version 5.1, 6.0 or 7.0 or above (depending on the platform)." It's strange that it supports IIS 7, if IIS 7 makes it obsolete. I've voted up your answer, but will wait for a day or two to accept in case anyone has additional information.

Comment: Yes, you can still install it, because Request Filtering does not support absolutely ALL features of URLScan (but it supports the most important one's)